# Write post outside the WP admin

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to make a directory theme with WordPress, and i want the user to be able to write a post without being inside the admin.

I can't seem to find any information about if this is possible.

Does anyone know how i could make it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't do this

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into the [XML-RPC support](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) in WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has something called XML-RPC, in Settings -> Writing. I've used it in the past for remote posting, take a look :

http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp

Answer (score 1):

Try TDO Mini Forms

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a form using the wp_insert_post function.